# References on food safety?

Tags: food-safety, resources

I'm looking for good, authoritative references on food safety topics. In particular I'd like to learn more about the different parts of various meats and fish, which parts are safe to eat, and what preparation steps are necessary for each to guarantee safety.

What would be a good place to look for this information?

Comment: I'm not sure what to make of this question... if there's actually a subject area for this (butchering? anatomy?) it's *definitely* not called "food processing". That term either refers to food processor appliances or commercial food processing (i.e. manufacture of packaged food products in massive quantities). I'm going to treat this as a question about food safety in general; feel free to clarify if I'm missing the point.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very broad question. My recommendation is to look up your specific product at 
the [US FDA Food Safety page](http://www.fda.gov/Food/FoodSafety/default.htm#psi).

Some of the topics treated are:

**Product-Specific Information**

Acidified and Low-Acid Canned Foods

Bottled Water & Carbonated Soft Drinks

Cheese Safety

Egg Safety

Fruits, Vegetables & Juices

Infant Formula

Medical Foods

Milk Safety

Seafood

**Food Allergens**

Consumer Information

Food Allergens Labeling

**Foodborne Illness**

Consumer Information

Foodborne Illness, Foodborne Pathogens & Natural Toxins

Interagency Coordination

**Food Contaminants & Adulteration**

Chemical Contaminants

Metals

Natural Toxins

Pesticides